# Code not executingExecuting in order

Tags: javascript, node.js

Having some troubles here (i'm fairly new) and havent been able to find  a propper answer.

The thing is i would expect it to first execute all the fetch function and creating the array and then the insertIntoDb function, but by console logging i see that the insertIntoDb is the first thing that gets executed so the spanishURls array is emty when it gets to that point and i get a mysql error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```js
function getAndInsertData(callback){
 //create query
 var sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName";
 //making query
 connection.query(sql, function(err, resultData) {
    if (err) throw err;
     //for each data perform an action
     resultData.forEach(function(data, index){
      //this is done by an npm library, nothing special
      sitemapper.fetch(sitemap.url).then(function(sites) {
       //get list of urls
       var urls = sites.sites;
       //filter for all urls in Spanish
       spanishUrls = getSpanishUrls(urls, sites,sitemap)
       //Printing the list of urls which works fine and is formatted in the propper way
       console.log(spanishUrls)
      })
     })

 });
 //Inserting the data into the database
 insertIntoDb(spanishUrls)

}



function insertIntoDb(query, values){
     connection.query("insert into urls (url, sitemap) VALUES ?", [values], function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("added urls to db");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Promise.all() to run .then() for each resultData.

```js
function getAndInsertData(callback){
 //create query
 var sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName";
 //making query
 connection.query(sql, function(err, resultData) {
if (err) throw err;
//for each data perform an action
      Promise.all(resultData.map(function(data, index) {
        return sitemapper.fetch(sitemap.url).then(function(sites) {
          //get list of urls
          var urls = sites.sites;
          //filter for all urls in Spanish
          spanishUrls = getSpanishUrls(urls, sites, sitemap)
          //Printing the list of urls which works fine and is formatted in the proper way
          console.log(spanishUrls)
        })
      }))
      .then(function() {
        //Inserting the data into the database
        insertIntoDb(spanishUrls)
      });
 });

}

function insertIntoDb(query, values){
     connection.query("insert into urls (url, sitemap) VALUES ?", [values], function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("added urls to db");
    });
}
```

Comment: Just tried that, but i get the error: resultPromise.then is not a function :(

Comment: That did work!! Thank you so much! I was really stuck here!

Comment: @Rever92. Happy to help ☺️. Could you please accept the answer if it resolved your issue.